# fetching record id passed through url in edit view suitecrm

Tags: suitecrm

i have created a custom button 'create note' in list view of leads. An extra column of create note appears as shown below in link(image).
through that 'create note' button i am sending the lead id as record in url as - http://localhost/cod/suitecrm/index.php?action=ajaxui#ajaxUILoc=index.php%3Fmodule%3DNotes%26action%3DEditView%26return_module%3DNotes%26return_action%3DDetailView%26record%3Da0deb972-35e7-d909-41be-5be96467233c.

after clicking on the create note button i want to fetch that record id and want to autofill the related field lead using that record lead id in create note.
i want the same functionality that appears after opening a lead below the history tab create note with autofill related lead name on list view of lead using that button 'create note' in list view

kindly help
links for images below:

drive.google.com/file/d/1SPJlSSg1qDgtkJEw5NX_5ZaUTgW8T2m1/view

drive.google.com/file/d/1EQcg_TI7FgjXCHgHVK-nhmEqCxsce69q/view

Comment: Please share us some code.